# Ionic 2 text-wrap font size

Tags: css, ionic2

**Ionic 2 app -** I have a list of items, I use `text-wrap` to avoid text cutting off when i increase font size however when text-wrap attribute is used the font seems to go back to what I assume is the default size for `text-wrap` attribute. How do I change `text-wrap` (default) font size?

***Font size increased - without text-wrap:***
[image]

***Font size increased - with text-wrap:***

[image]

**HTML**

```
  <ion-list text-wrap>
    <div *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
      <button ion-item (click)="goToPageFn(item)" class="app-font-25">
        <b>{{item.name}}</b>
      </button>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
```

**CSS:** [edit]

```
text-wrap {
    font-size: 25px;
}
.app-font-25 {
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Include your css code as well. You can try using !important in your font-size value so that it doesn't pick the default value

Comment: @AishApp updated. Where do I find css for `text-wrap` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic2 have in built css for button which makes it to not wrap the text content. If you want to alter the size of the text and as well to wrap it, modify your code as below

```
<ion-list>
    <div *ngFor="let item of menuItems">
        <button ion-item (click)="goToPageFn(item)" class="app-font-25">
            <b>{{item.name}}</b>
        </button>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

Your CSS:

```
.app-font-25 ion-label{
    white-space: inherit;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
```

**text-wrap** is not required both in your html and css.